# How to use local stored X/Y/Z.png tiles from OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

In the OpenStreetMap Wiki there is a [nice example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example) about how to use Local Tiles with OpenLayers, but this is for version 2 of OpenLayers. I'm looking for the same with OpenLayers 3. Are there any good examples of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In openlayers 3 you can do this like this (you need access to local files from the browser):

```
var newLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
            url: 'maps/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
    newLayer
    ],
  controls: [],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([4.666389, 50.009167], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4,
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 20
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All decent browsers limit what a webpage can do with local files, for good reason. Allowing a webpage to read the contents of local files would open up severe privacy and security issues.

OpenLayers 3 works best with the default *canvas* renderer, which requires that the tiles are readable to the script.

You should be able to display local tiles with OpenLayers 3 if you use the *DOM* renderer. Note that only the canvas renderer supports vector data.

Answer (score 0):

A working example code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
       lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
     <style>
       .map {
         height: 256px;
         width: 256px;
       }
     </style>
     <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h2>My Map</h2>
     <div id="map" class="map"></div>
         <!-- Map -->
         <script src="libraries/ol.js"></script>
         <script>
                 var map = new ol.Map({
                   layers: [
                         new ol.layer.Tile({
                                 source: new ol.source.OSM({
                                         url: '../Maps/OSM/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                                         })
                           })
                   ],
                   controls: [],
                   target: 'map',
                   view: new ol.View({
                    <!--
                         center: ol.proj.transform([11.622789, 48.052647], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    -->
                         center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.622789, 48.052647]),
                         zoom: 18,
                         minZoom: 1,
                         maxZoom: 20
                   })
                 });
         </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

which works fine in the chrome browser:

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files 2nd.html
```